# getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) cause ANR on android 11 and android 12

Tags: android, firebase, android-11, android-12, anr

this is my code

```
fun createDirDownload(): File {

        val fileDir = activity?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!
        if (!fileDir.exists()) {
            fileDir.mkdirs()
        }

        return fileDir
    }
```

The firebase crashlytics shows this method:  getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) caused ANR.
But I don't know why and how to solve the problem.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `this is firebase error` That code has nothing to do with FireBase so it cannot give a FireBase error.

Comment: if (!fileDir.exists()) {
            if ( !fileDir.mkdirs()) return;
        } Always check the return value of mkdirs() and dont continue if it fails.

Comment: @blackapps Maybe my description is confusing. I am not saying this is firebase error, but I just give the error log by firebase crashlytics. The ANR error is caused by this method: getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).

Comment: That is hard to believe. The only thing that should happen is that the Download directory gets created. You dont have to call mkdirs() as -as said- the directory is created by that call.